# Touch Screen event for tiny2451->S3c2451 ARM9 core

Tags: kernel, arm, linux-device-driver, touchscreen

I have worked on 2440 touch screen worked perfectly. Now I want switch to tiny2451. 
   for testing my touch screen I used  cat /dev/input/event0 ---> It shows some ASCII character in my debug port.
Same thing I had tried for tiny2451 board cat /dev/input/event0---> It does not show anything.
   But I am getting the same by cat /dev/touchscreen-1wire --->It shows some ASCII character in my debug port.

Now my question is : what will be the change in the /etc/profile file. Below is my 2440 board configuration.

```
=========================================================================
# Ash profile 
# vim: syntax=sh

# No core files by default
ulimit -S -c 0 > /dev/null 2>&1

USER="`id -un`"
LOGNAME=$USER
PS1='[\u@\h \W]\# '
PATH=$PATH

HOSTNAME=`/bin/hostname`

export USER LOGNAME PS1 PATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib
export QTDIR=/usr/local/Qt
export QWS_MOUSE_PROTO=tslib:/dev/input/event0
export TSLIB_CALIBFILE=/etc/pointercal
export TSLIB_CONFFILE=/usr/local/etc/ts.conf
export TSLIB_CONSOLEDEVICE=none
export TSLIB_FBDEVICE=/dev/fb0
export TSLIB_PLUGINDER=/usr/local/lib/ts
export TSLIB_TSDEVICE=/usr/local/lib/ts
export TSLIB_TSEVENTTYPE=INPUT
export QWS_DISPLAY=LinuxFB:mmWidth=105:mmHeight=140
========================================================================
```

Please, reply who have worked on tiny2451.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer. Thanks to all.

Ans:Comment/delete this line.

```
export TSLIB_TSDEVICE=/usr/local/lib/ts
```